# Does emacs have a way to align the '='s inside a C++ enum

Tags: emacs, alignment

I've frequently had code blocks that look like this:

```
enum class MyEnum {
    first = 1,
    second_really_long_line = 2,
    third = 3
};
```

That I want to look like this:

```
enum class MyEnum {
    first                   = 1,
    second_really_long_line = 2,
    third                   = 3
};
```

Is there a way, in emacs, that I can get the `=` all in the same column for the body of the `enum`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Select the entire block and run `M-x align`.

Emacs' C modes arrange for `align` to do useful things in quite a few situations, so it is often worth trying if you have an alignment problem.